# How to find discord password with console script

Tags: discord, passwords

is there any way to find discord password with google console page, i've tried to reset the password but wont work, i found the discord token but is curious is there any other way to find the password other than reseting it, or is it just impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve a password in Discord, imagine the security breach this can create.

The token will not help too.